# assigning a method result to a variable in ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, methods

I'm sure it would be hard to find an easier question, but I'm a complete newbie. I have searched extensively and for some reason can't find the answer to this. Here's my code:

```
puts "Enter F for Fahrenheit and C for Celsius."

x = gets.chomp.downcase

def ftoc(fahrenheit)
  (fahrenheit.to_f - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0)
end

if x == "f"
  puts "Enter your temp:"
  temp = gets.chomp.to_i
  ftoc temp
elsif x == "c"
  puts "Enter your temp:"
  temp = gets.chomp.to_i
  ctof temp
else
  puts "That does not compute."
end
```

I'm just trying to get the returned result of the method into a variable so I can use it elsewhere....

Comment: new to this site too, and I have no idea why my loop code is all smushed together. It really doesn't matter anyway I guess.

Comment: You need to indent with four spaces to get it to format properly, or highlight it and push the `{}` button to do that for you.

Comment: People can be harsh judges here, but I wouldn't worry too much about it. In the long run it all works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that calls like `ctof temp` just initiate a method and then, as you're not putting the result anywhere, discard it immediately.

To clean up this code let's organize it better:

```
# Temperature conversion method
def ftoc(fahrenheit)
  (fahrenheit.to_f - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0)
end

# User input method
def temperature_prompt!
  puts "Enter F for Fahrenheit and C for Celsius."
  x = gets.chomp.downcase

  case (x)
  when "f"
    puts "Enter your temp:"
    temp = gets.chomp.to_i
    ftoc temp
  when "c"
    puts "Enter your temp:"
    temp = gets.chomp.to_i
    ctof temp
  else
    puts "That does not compute."
  end
end
```

Now you can make use of the fact that in Ruby things like `if` and `case` actually return values. In this case it's the value of the last thing to execute in each block, so that result isn't discarded, it's just passed along:

```
temp = temperature_prompt!
```

If you enter an invalid value you get the result of `puts` which is conveniently `nil`.

Here's something to consider: Ruby is very good at parsing arbitrary text if you can describe the patterns. Here's a simple input routine:

```
def temperature_prompt!
  puts "Enter degrees (e.g. 8F, 2C)"

  case (input = gets.chomp.downcase)
  when /(\d+)f/
    ftoc $1
  when /(\d+)c/
    ctof $1
  else
    puts "That does not compute."
  end
end
```

You could add to those patterns to allow things like `-2C` and `3.4°F` if you wanted.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time and all the extra info. I'll definitely look into it. The code works now and prints out the converted temp, but I'm still not sure how to put the answer into a variable to be recalled later on in the program...  After the code is run, I'd like to print out something like:  puts "the converted variable is " + def_result_variable    

or something like that...

Comment: The [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) book is available online and is a great resource for getting started in Ruby. If you like that version there's a more up-to-date one available from the publisher that's worth buying.